# Google Compute Engine - GPU seems not available

Tags: gpu, google-compute-engine

I'm new to Google Compute Engine and I'd just like to have a VM with a GPU but I simply can't select one.

I already requested+got these quotas. What am I missing?

- NVIDIA P100 GPUs = 1
- GPUs (All regions) = 1

[image: AllRegions]

[image: P100]

[image: CreateVM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the GPUs only work with N1 instances as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#restrictions).

> Instances with GPUs have specific restrictions that make them behave differently than other instance types.
>
> - GPUs are currently only supported with general-purpose N1 machine types.